# Kivy-ios import python modules

Tags: python, ios, xcode, kivy

I am using kivy-ios to build an app on a Mac. When I build the app in Xcode I get the `ImportError: No Module Named Requests`
I've scrubbed the internet looking for a solution. I have put the requests folder in my app directory (actually I've tried putting it in every directory I can think of.)and still no joy.

when I open python in a terminal and type `import requests` it works. I am using python 2.7.

Has anyone else figured out a solution for importing non-kivy modules that are not supported on ./toolchain.py?

Is there a way to change the path that Xcode uses to find python? Is it possible that Xcode is looking for the built in version of python on Mac even though the terminal is finding the one I installed?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Anyone had this problem and fixed it?

Comment: Try copying the module into the directory with your main.py script. That way when you say 'import foo' it will find foo in your project's directory

Comment: ./toolchain.py pip install requests is what ended up doing it.

Comment: I'll add to this, I also had to run `toolchain pip install chardet` after doing `toolchain pip install requests`